# Use the => operator in boolean expressions

Tags: dart, arrow-functions

How could I use the "=>" operator in boolean expressions? For example, the following declaration is wrong, since "isOpen = !isOpen" returns a boolean value:

```
// not a good function declaration
void toggle => isOpen = !isOpen;
```

I was thinking in something similar to this:

```
void toggle => shutUp(isOpen = !isOpen);
```

Where `shutUp()` is a function that returns a `void` value and accepts any boolean parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var isOpen = false;
var toggle = () => isOpen = !isOpen;
toggle();
print(isOpen);
toggle();
print(isOpen);
```

Comment: => x is a shorthand for { return x; }. So a function can be written as: toggle() => isOpen = !isOpen; and an anonymous function is same, just without a name: () => isOpen = !isOpen;. [More on that here.](https://www.dartlang.org/resources/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-7)

Comment: It's not strange that it works. It's almost the same as `bool toggle() => isOpen = !isOpen;`, only written in a more convoluted way. A way that also probably doesn't work for methods - you can't implement a `void toggle()` method signature with `var toggle`. I don't recommend using this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `=>` for void functions.

As Mezoni writes, `=> e` is shorthand notation for `{ return e; }`. You should not write a `return e` in a void function, so you should also not use `=>`.

Just write:

```dart
void toggle() { isOpen = !isOpen; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart language allows use expression as a function.
This feature called function expression.
This feature allows that the expression can have a parameters.

Example.

```
void main() {
  var sum = (a, b) => a + b; // <==== function expression
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print(sum(i, i));
  }
}
```

In this case lexeme `=>` does not means an operator. It means a lexeme which marks the beginning of the function body (of the function expression).

This is not the only one possible syntax for use function expressions.
It was just an example for understanding.